# Rails - Using Devise current_user on nested resource without direct access to model with user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a rails 4 app where users can create projects and add posts to projects. Posts will consist of text plus images with optional captions, so I have a photos model that stores the images and their captions.

Users have many projects, projects have many posts and posts have many photos

My routes look like this:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :posts
end
resources :posts do
  resources :photos
end
```

Authorising by current_user works for projects and also posts because posts are directly related to projects which have the user_id stored with them. Photos only link directly to posts so I can't do this as I do in the posts controller:

```
def set_project
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:project_id])
end
```

Is there a way of using current_user on photos in a similar way so that only the author of the project can add,edit,delete photos to their posts?

Currently in my photos controller I get the associated post via:

```
def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
end
```

But that obviously has no current_user authorisation. I need some way of finding the id of the project to which the post belongs then using current_user on that inside the photos controller.

Comment: Do you need `current_user.projects.find(params[:project_id].posts.find(params[:post_id]).photos`? Or you can define a scope in one of your models: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: I think that's the sort of thing I need. I've tried `@post = current_user.projects.find(params[:project_id].posts.find(params[:post_id]))` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rule of thumb is not to have more than two levels of nested resource otherwise you'll be too busy to take care of them(*forget the source, maybe from my experience*)

For your case, I suggest not to set nested resource for photos.(Or set it nested under user)

```
resources project do
  resources posts
end

resources photo
```

Then model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  has_many :projects
end
```

This also makes sense in real world. A post is under a project, that's reasonable. But how about a photo? If you have a photo to show your idea of layout in one post, can future post use this photo again? Say the client want to compare before and after? Definitely should. So, a photo is better independent from post, in reasonable logic.

And then, all your questions are not question now.

**Add: To answer question in comment**
In my opinion there are three ways to relate(not associate) post with photos:

1. Insert photos ids in post content, this is the most preferred, by this the post writer can control the position of photo. No association required.
2. Many to many relationship. A bit complex.
3. Use a serialized column in post to store an array of photo ids it mentioned.

The other way is your method, post has_many photos. In this case a photo will have FIXED post_id and won't be able to be called in other post. You can do it if the result is acceptable. But even in this way, you DO NOT need a nested resource as well.

Comment: The purpose of the app is that people share their progress whilst creating something so every post they make is of new progress and photos need to be associated with that post. A project is a series of posts documenting progress with photos. As far as I can tell that means I have to associate photos directly with posts by having a has_many belongs_to relationship?

Comment: @AidanZealley, I understand the basic of your app. There is no need to associate posts with photos in my opinion. You can just write photo id in post and the job is done.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure we are on the same wavelength :/

When the app displays a post it needs to go find the photos associated with that post, so surely there has to be a relationship between photos and posts?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I think I will try and incorporate your first suggestion to prevent locking myself into having a fixed post_id :)